# Error al crear una conexión en SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Instalé el programa junto a Oracle Database 11g Express Edition y la versión necesaria de Java pero al crear una nueva conexión se produce el siguiente error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo? Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira si el servicio está arrancado.

En la carpeta de Oracle hay un enlace que indica "*Start Database*" o "*Iniciar Database*". Ejecútalo y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: No me aparece en la carpeta de Oracle. ¿Quizás se debe a un error en la instalación?

Comment: Puede ser. Prueba a reinstalarlo. Te chequeará la instalación y posiblemente corrija los errores de ésta.